# How to fix text displaying on top of table line

Tags: tables, longtable

This is the problem that I want to fix

[image]

The text is displaying on top of table line,
This is the code the I am using (generated by https://www.tablesgenerator.com) :

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|ccc|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Thème} &
\multirow{2}{*}{ID} &
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{User Story} &
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Prio-\\ rité\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{3-5}
&
&
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{En tant que} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{je veux} &
Afin de &
\\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Modélsiation} &
US1.1 &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{Développeur}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Étudier la structure\\  des 
données.\end{tabular}} &
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Fournir une structure\\ optimisée pour\\  
faciliter\\ l'accès et l'analyse\\  des données.\end{tabular}} &
1 \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-6} 
&
US1.2 &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Définir les KPIs.} &
&
1 \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-6} 
&
US1.3 &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Modéliser l'entrepôt \\ de 
données.\end{tabular}} &
&
1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3):

- Unfortunately you not provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, so we haven't any information about used document class nor about used fonts and your page layout.
- Your table can be written far more simple by use of the `tabularray` package: without using nested tables or mini pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec  = {l Q[c,m] l X[l, m] X[l, m] X[0.3, c, cmd={\hskip 0pt}]},
             cell{1}{1,2,Z} = {r=2}{},
             row{1,2} = {c, m},
             }
Thème   & ID    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  User Story
                    &   &   & Prioriorité       \\ 
        &       &   En tant que
                    & je veux
                        & Afin de 
                            &                   \\
\SetCell[r=3]{c}  Modélsiation
        & US1.1 & \SetCell[r=3]{c}  Développeur
                    & Étudier la structure des données
                        & \SetCell[r=3]{c}  Fournir une structure optimisée pour faciliter  l'accès et l'analyse des données
                            &   1               \\
        & US1.2 &   & Définir les KPIs.
                        &   &   1               \\
        & US1.3 &   & Modéliser l'entrepôt de données.
                        &   &   1               \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Example Table}
\label{tab:my-table}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX StackExchange!

In that cell, you have a `tabular` inside your larger `tabular`. By replacing the inner `tabular` environment with a `minipage` environment, you can write whatever text you'd like in that cell (so long as its height doesn't surpass the height of the three adjacent rows, in which case it will overflow the border again). This is somewhat of an *ad hoc* solution, because the multirow package isn't really set up to deal with multi-line messages.

**Result:**

[image: An updated table without text on a cell border]

---

I've cleaned up other parts of your code to make it more readable, but I've left the general structure intact. I'd like to gently suggest considering letting LaTeX handle the typesetting of hyphens and line breaks in lieu of doing it yourself (e.g. in `Prio-\\ rité`). This tends to make the process a lot less frustrating :)

```tex
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Thème} &
\multirow{2}{*}{ID} &
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{User Story} &
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Prio-\\ rité\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{3-5}
&
&
En tant que &
je veux &
Afin de & \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Modélsiation} & US1.1 &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{Développeur}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{c}Étudier la structure\\  des 
données.\end{tabular}} &
\multirow{3}{*}{%
\begin{minipage}[10cm]{10em}\centering Fournir une structure optimisée pour 
faciliter l'accès et l'analyse des données.\end{minipage}%
} &
1 \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-6} 
&
US1.2 &
&
Définir les KPIs. &
&
1 \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-6} 
&
US1.3 &
&
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Modéliser l'entrepôt \\ de 
données.\end{tabular} &
&
1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{j’aime créer les tableaux}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

Bonjour, et bienvenue à \TeX\ StackExchange ! Voici d’autre texte sous le tableau.
```